# Get all the descendant nodes (also the leaves) of a certain node

Tags: javascript, html, tree

I have an html document consists of a `<div id="main">`. Inside this `div` may be several levels of nodes, without a precise structure because is the user who creates the document content.
I want to use a **JavaScript** function that returns all nodes within `div id="main"`. Any tag is, taking into account that there may be different levels of children.

For example, if I has this document:

```
...

<div id="main">

    <h1>bla bla</h1>

    <p>
        <b>fruits</b> apple<i>text</i>.
        <img src="..">image</img>
    </p>

    <div>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
    </div>

    <p>..</p>

</div>
...
```

The function `getNodes` would return an array of object nodes (I don't know how to represent it, so I list them):

```
[h1, #text (= bla bla), p, b, #text (= fruits), #text (= _apple), i, #text (= text), img, #text (= image), div, p, p, p, #text (= ..)]
```

As we see from the example, you must return **all** nodes, *even the leaf nodes (ie #text node)*.

For now I have this function that returns all nodes except leaf:

```
function getNodes() {
    var all = document.querySelectorAll("#main *");
    for (var elem = 0; elem < all.length; elem++) {
        //do something..
    }
}
```

In fact, this feature applied in the above example returns:

```
[H1, P, B, I, IMG, DIV, P, P, P]
```

There aren't #text nodes.
Also, if text elements returned by that method in this way:

```
all[elem].children.length
```

I obtain that (I tested on `<p>fruits</p>`) `<p>` is a *leaf* node.
But if I build the DOM tree it is clear that is not a leaf node, and that in this example the leaf nodes are the `#text`...

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Classic case for recursion into the DOM.

```
function getDescendants(node, accum) {
    var i;
    accum = accum || [];
    for (i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
        accum.push(node.childNodes[i])
        getDescendants(node.childNodes[i], accum);
    }
    return accum;
}
```

and

```
getDescendants( document.querySelector("#main") );
```

Comment: You count them wrong. The function can not return more nodes than are there. Did you consider the whitespace-only text nodes between elements? Comment nodes maybe? It's trivial to modify the function to filter out those unwanted nodes, I leave that to you.

Comment: Mmm ok, and how you count it?

Comment: I do not count it at all. All I did was write a function that recurses into the DOM and builds an array of all the nodes it finds, depth first. If you look at the code line by line then you will find that it is impossible for that function to return a wrong result. Therefore your expectations must be off.

Comment: I understand that you wrote a function that works correctly. But I would like a function that returns 15 nodes: `[h1, #text (= bla bla), p, b, #text (= fruits), #text (= _apple), i, #text (= text), img, #text (= image), div, p, p, p, #text (= ..)]`. And your will return 25 nodes: `[text, h1, text, text, p, text, b, text, text, i, text, text, img, text, text, div, text, p, text, p, text, text, p, text, text]`.. I only asked why..

Comment: Read my first comment again. There is your reason. :)

Comment: I take it that the single `if` required to modify the function isn't a problem, since you're clear on what nodes you want to ignore.

Comment: Great. :) And you've learned something about how the DOM *really* looks like, too. This kind of knowledge will be useful at some point.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the already existing and perfectly functional answer, I find it worth mentioning that one can do away with the recursion and the many resulting function calls by simply navigating via the `firstChild`, `nextSibling`, and `parentNode` properties:

```
function getDescendants(node) {
    var list = [], desc = node, checked = false, i = 0;
    do {
        checked || (list[i++] = desc);
        desc =
            (!checked && desc.firstChild) ||
            (checked = false, desc.nextSibling) ||
            (checked = true, desc.parentNode);
    } while (desc !== node);
    return list;
}
```

(Whenever we encounter a new node, we add it to the list, then try going to its first child node. If such does not exist, get the next sibling instead. Whenever no child node or following sibling is found, we go back up to the parent, while setting the `checked` flag to avoid adding that to the list again or reentering its descendant tree.)

This will, in virtually every case, improve performance greatly. Not that there is nothing left to optimize here, e.g. one could cache the nodes where we descend further into the hierarchy so as to later get rid of the `parentNode` when coming back up. I leave implementing this as an exercise for the reader.

Keep in mind though that iterating through the DOM like this will rarely be the bottleneck in a script. Unless you are going through a large DOM tree many tens/hundreds of times a second, that is — in which case you probably ought to think about avoiding that if at all possible, rather than simply optimizing it.

Answer (score 0):

the `children` property only returns element nodes. If you want all children, I would suggest using the `childNodes` property. Then you can loop through this nodeList, and eliminate nodes that have nodeType of `Node.ELEMENT_NODE` or pick which other node types you would be interested in

so try something like:

```
var i, j, nodes
var result=[] 
var all = document.querySelectorAll("#main *");
for (var elem = 0; elem < all.length; elem++) {
    result.push(all[elem].nodeName)

    nodes = all[elem].childNodes;
    for (i=0, j=nodes.length; i<j; i++) {
        if (nodes[i].nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            result.push(nodes[i].nodeValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think there is an error in `elem[0].nodeName` so I change to `all[0].nodeName` and the result is `["H1", undefined, "H1", undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, "H1", undefined, "H1", undefined, "H1", "H1", undefined, undefined, undefined, "H1", "H1", "H1", undefined]`.. doesnt' work :(

Comment: I've updated it, I wrote the code, found the errors, fixed it and then pasted the original broken code - oops

Comment: Thanks, now it works. There's only a problem. The array contains also the charatcher `↵`, so the number of elements are 20 and not 15. How can I make sure to delete these characters? I think the problem is the `\n` `\t` ( other?). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the html tags and not the `#text`, you can just simply use this:`<elem>.querySelectorAll("*");`